# Check for duplicates when creating children for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I would like to check that I am not creating a child with a duplicate title. However, I am not sure of the correct way to check and compare. Here's a code example of how the div's children are added:

```
this.foo = function(inputTitle)
{
    var title = inputTitle;

    var $ItemContainer = $("#ItemContainer");
    $ItemContainer.append('<div class="Item" title="'+title+'"></div>');

    // Continue to build the child
    var $thisItem = $ItemContainer.children('.Item[title='+title+']');
    $thisItem.append('<div class="ItemTitle">'+title+'</div>');
   // .....
}
```

The class will always be `Item`. **How can I check that `#ItemContainer` does not already have a child with a duplicate title?**

Comment: By the way, title is not a valid attribute for a div

Comment: This is how the code has been, and it works somehow. Most of it is magic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will tell you if there are any divs with a given title

```
var exists = $('div[title="' + title + '"]').length > 0;
```

Comment: This gives a Syntax error of unrecognized expression ="Test", from the jquery-1.3.2.min

Comment: Ah, it was because you forgot to put an end ] in the code. Should be `var exists = $('div[title="'+title+'"]').length > 0;` When I fixed it, it works nicely.